# App is getting closed soon after opening in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

Downloaded one .ipa file from hockeyapp.net.
Copy .ipa file to Desktop, rename it to .zip file
Extract that .zip file and you will get directory with application name
Check that directory you will find app file in Payload folder, copy this app file
Go to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Now here you'll see many directories with long hexadecimal names, these all are simulators.
To find your desired simulator, sort these directories using "Arranged By > Date Modified".

Select that simulator file and go to below location.

/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/
Create new folder name with  and paste app file in that folder
Open Terminal and run below command to install this application
xcrun simctl install booted

I have used: xcrun simctl install booted ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5834ECE9-976E-4F72-BC0A-641A305EF0E0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/download-myPilot/myPilotiOS.app

It successfully installed the application in the simulator but when i tried to open the same it got closed soon after opening.

iPhone simulator: iPhone 6s
iOS: 10.2
xcode: 8.3

Please let me know whether there is a problem with the installation process or the ipa file was not made to support in simulator.

Comment: you don't have access to the raw code? the .xcodeproj?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your build is for real device with ARM architecture.
in this case you can't run it on simulator

You can try to upload you build on https://appetize.io/upload, just to make sure that the problem is with IPA

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not knew this way to upload. Thanks again. Upvote for that

Comment: But can you please tell me, is there any validity for the uploaded build. May be like one week or is it for ever?

Comment: i'm not sure, i guess you can ask these guys in twitter